# java.io.File constructor behaviour or perhaps multithreading issue?

Tags: java, multithreading, file

I have the following code:

```
class Abcd{
//wired by spring to give the directory filePath ="/var/tmp/"
private String filePath;

 public void myMethod(String id, String date){
  filePath= filePath+ id+ "_" + date;
  File f = new File(filePath);
  if(f.exists){//Do something}
  else{
   System.out.println("File not found at file path:"+filePath);
  }
 }
}
```

The above code is behaving weird , intermittently the filePath contains all the files of directory /var/tmp/ . So , if /var/tmp directory contains two files called "id1_01012017" and "id2_10102017".

This is the **intermittent** output

File not found at file path:/var/tmp/id1_01012017id2_10102017

Am unable to figure out whats happening

Comment: The code is indeed not thread safe. If `myMethod` is called from several threads the observed behaviour may happen.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to maintain that `filePath` remains *immutable*. You will find that if you change this line:

```
filePath = filePath + id + "_" + date;
```

to the following:

```
String tempFilePath = filePath + id + "_" + date;
```

and operate on `tempFilePath` instead of `filePath`, your code will become thread-safe and work as expected.

Comment: Even if it was a threading issue the output should have been something like:
File not found at file path:/var/tmp/id1_01012017/var/tmp/id1_01012017id2_10102017
right?

Comment: Not necessarily. If two threads are running through the same code, there's no deterministic way to predict the output.